# Form post to another page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, http-post, forms

I am fairly new to C# and asp.net and am having trouble showing something submitted in a form. The form element is a  tag. The drop-down info is pulled from a data base and displays correctly. It's just getting it to post to another page after the form is submitted is where I am having the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Contact.aspx:

```
<form action="Default.aspx" method="post" data-transition="pop">
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="topEmails">Business Entity ID:</label>
    <select name="topEmails" id="topEmails" data-native-menu="false" 
            runat="server">
    </select>
</div>
<input type="submit" data-iconpos="right" data-inline="true" 
       data-icon="plus" name="sendMessage" id="sendMessage" value="Send Info">
</form>
```

Contact.aspx.cs:

```
AdventureWorks2012DataContext db = new AdventureWorks2012DataContext();

var emails = (from b in db.EmailAddresses
              select new { b.EmailAddressID, b.BusinessEntityID }).Take(20);
topEmails.DataTextField = "BusinessEntityID";
topEmails.DataValueField = "BusinessEntityID";
topEmails.DataSource = emails;
topEmails.DataBind();
```

Default.aspx.cs:

```
FormSuccessBID.InnerHtml = "Business Entity ID: " +  Request.Form["topEmails"] + "";
```

Any ideas why this wouldn't be working?

**Update:**

Contact.aspx:

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<h2 style="text-align: center;">Contact Kyle</h2>

<form action="Default.aspx" method="post" data-transition="pop">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="userFName">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="firstName" id="uFName">
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="userLName">Last Name :</label>
        <input type="text" name="lastName" id="uLName">
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="productsCategories">Products:</label>
        <select name="productCategories" id="productCategories" data-native-menu="false" runat="server"></select>
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="topEmails">Business Entity ID:</label>
        <select name="topEmails" id="topEmails" data-native-menu="false" runat="server"></select>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" data-iconpos="right" data-inline="true" data-icon="plus" name="sendMessage" id="sendMessage" value="Send Info">
</form>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Is `Request.Form["topEmails"]` empty or does it not contain the value selected by the user?

Comment: It is returning as null after a selection is made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing "runat='server'" in your form definition.

In ASP.NET you're also allowed one form per page. Not sure from what you're posted if you're trying to put multiple forms on there, but if you are, it's not going to work.

I think all you need to do to accomplish what you want is have an ASP.NET button on the page, with the postbackURL set to the page you want to go to. (Of course, you need to do this in a server-side form)

I think you're mixing ASP.NET methods with other, different technologies. (From the look of it, you probably used classic ASP or PHP perhaps?)

If you can't use .NET for whatever reason, the ID/name of the field is not going to be what you're expecting. You need to inspect the form post and find its value - something along the lines of "clt00_somethingelse_topEmails". (Again, this is going to be a heck of a lot easier if you use the .NET way of doing things, but you may have a requirement not to)

Comment: I just added my full Contact.aspx page. The other form elements post just fine, it's just the topEmails which doesn't

Comment: I edited my response - but ASP.NET doesn't keep the friendly names in the actual HTML. You're probably looking for the wrong name in the request.form call. Try printing out all the fields from request.form and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: I got the following when looking at the request.form call 'Request.Form{firstName=QWER&lastName=TYU&ctl00%24MainContent%24productCategories=322&ctl00%24MainContent%24topEmails=50&sendMessage=Send+Info}' I entered ctl00%24MainContent%24topEmails as the variable instead on topEmails and it still comes up as null.

Comment: Try ctl00_MainContent_topEmails - looks like they're URL encoded